# IReport: Detail band does not overflow to next page

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two text fields inside a detail band. Here follows band XML code:

```
<band height="40" splitType="Prevent">
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
       <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="67cd0dfb-9a6d-4468-            8aac-3f48e539c584"/>
      <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Resposta}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
      <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"          uuid="c7fa90d3-2b11-4127-b319-5461a80acb2d"/>
      <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Nome Questão}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
</band>
```

As you can see, the text fields position type is "float", stretch type is "Relative to band height" print in first whole band is "true" print when detail overflows is "true" and stretch with overflow is also "true".
Band's Stretch Type is set to "Prevent".

I don't get it why it does not print all the rows I should get with my query. It should continue printing in more pages until all rows were displayed.
Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you change the stretch type to something other than "prevent"?

Comment: Still does not work...

Answer (score -1):

First select your band details and set Stretch Type as "Stretch".

Secondly check and set following details by selecting your field :
Position type: float
Stretch type: relative to tallest object
Stretch with overflow: true (Checked)
Print repeated values: true (Checked)

Even if this not worked then add one more configuration -
Show out of bound content: true (Checked)

Note : If your field wrapped with frame then set frame properties also as above.

If you do above setting then I think there is no need to set detail overflows as "true".